# Configure a Azure VM with two NIC's

Tags: powershell, azure, networking, azure-storage

I'm implementing a site-to-site VPN using Site-to-Site VPN in Azure Virtual Network using Windows Server 2012 Routing and Remote Access Service (RRAS).

To configure it, i need One Windows Server 2012 machine with two NIC.
Using Microsoft Azure Powershell,I'm trying to create it.

I am following the steps from this [article at microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn848315.aspx).

1. I select the VM from Azure Image Gallery.

   ```
   $image = Get-AzureVMImage -ImageName "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201408.01-en.us-127GB.vhd"
   ```
2. Then I create a VM configuration with its name, no.of cores(4), and image. I dont what is availabilityset.

   $vm = New-AzureVMConfig -Name "MultiNicVM" -InstanceSize "ExtraLarge" -Image $image.ImageName –AvailabilitySetName “MyAVSet”
3. Create login for the VM.

   Add-AzureProvisioningConfig –VM $vm -Windows -AdminUserName “” -Password “”

4.Add our Additional NIC with Static IP address

```
Add-AzureNetworkInterfaceConfig -Name "Ethernet1" -SubnetName "Midtier" 
-StaticVNetIPAddress "10.1.1.111" -VM $vm
```

5. Configuration for Default NIC. For default NIC, it should be public IP, why it is given a private Ip?

   Set-AzureSubnet -SubnetNames "Frontend" -VM $vm
   Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress "10.1.0.100" -VM $vm
6. Create your VM, with "MultiNIC-VNet" already exists as a Virtual Network.

   New-AzureVM -ServiceName "MultiNIC-CS" –VNetName “MultiNIC-VNet” –VM $vm

At the Step 6, it get an error "hosted service does not exist"

```
New-AzureVM : ResourceNotFound: The hosted service does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureVM -ServiceName "MultiNIC-CS" –VNetName “MultiNIC-VNet” –VM $vm
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.PersistentVMs.NewAzureVMCommand
```

All i need a NIC with public IP and a NIC with private IP which acts as a local area network for the site to site VPN. But the default NIC is given a private IP, a another NIC with public IP will be created automatically?

Why do i get an error "hosted service does not exist"?

Answer (score 1):

Location or AffinityGroup parameter not being specified in New-AzureVM
(one of these is required when creating new service)